# Cannot commit Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

I'm trying to commit in Xcode, however, it says I have 3648 uncommitted files
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Xx4.jpg)

When I try to commit I get this
[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGj4T.jpg)

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Fix your project so that the Pods are not part of what should be committed, only code and other resources _you_ have created should be part of the repository and your commits. One way forward here could be to create a .gitignore file.

Comment: Do not use Xcode's Git integration features. Learn to use Git properly, either at the command line (Terminal) or with a better GUI (I recommend Sourcetree).